# Adding dynamically elements to a for using jquery with Razor

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm noob with jquery, razor, Bootstrap, etc. I'm trying to learn by myself.

I am using mvc, I have a list and I want to add some new elements.

How can I do that??

Here my code:

```
@{var otherTechsList = Model.Technologies.Where(r =>
    r.CategoryId == null).ToList();}
@for (int x = 0; x < otherTechsList.Count; x++) {
    var technTrId = "techTr" + otherTechsList[x].TechnologyId.ToString();
    <div id="@technTrId" class="panel-body">
       */ My Elements here /*
    </div>
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: can get specific with u r question,  i have a list and i want to add some new elements. means where is ur list, is it dropdown or else what ?

Comment: I edit my question. Thank you, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

if your div error, you can use @Html.Raw() or inside you code

```
@{ var otherTechsList = Model.Technologies.Where(r =>
                            r.CategoryId == null).ToList();
                    @for (int x = 0; x < otherTechsList.Count; x++)
                    {
                        var technTrId = "techTr" + otherTechsList[x].TechnologyId.ToString();
                        <div id="@technTrId" class="panel-body">
                                                                   <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4" style="align-items:baseline">
                                        @Html.TextBox("TechnologyName", otherTechsList[x].TechnologyName)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Technologies[x].TTmLevelId, Model.Technologies[x].TtmLevel,
                                                    new
                                                    {
                                                        @class = "form-control",
                                                        @onchange = "ValidateAr(selectedIndex,'" + otherTechsList[x].TechnologyId + "', 'tech', 'techLvlName', id)",
                                                        id = "tecnologiesId" + otherTechsList[x].TechnologyId
                                                    })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Technologies[x].TtmlevelValue,
                                                              new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 100)),
                                                    new
                                                    {
                                                        @class = "form-control",
                                                        @onchange = "ValidateAr(selectedIndex,'" + otherTechsList[x].TechnologyId + "', 'tech', 'techLvlName', id)",
                                                        id = "tecnologiesId" + otherTechsList[x].TechnologyId
                                                    })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" style="padding:5px; margin:2px;">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="top:3px;"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>

                     }}
```

Edit: Sorry, i forget. I have a button to add new elements in my list.

```
                                        <button href="#" id="addNewTech" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" style="margin-left:4px">
```

And i my script i need to build a function to add the elements, something like that i think so: 
    $("#addNewTech").click(function (e) {
             */code i doesn't know here /* }